# .NET Core 2.2 SqlException: Invalid object name 'ApplicationUsers'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 applications called ManagementStudio and DocumentStudio. I have compiled ManagementStudio into several assemblies that DocumentStudio references.

I use the same Database for both applications but they are separated by different schemas. E.g. ManagementStudio.ApplicationUsers and DocumentStudio.Documents

In DocumentStudio, this is my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<DocumentStudioDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString)));

string assemblyName = typeof(ManagementStudioDbContext).Namespace;
services.AddDbContext<ManagementStudioDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString),
        optionsBuilder =>
            optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName)
    )
);
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
        = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();

});

var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
{
    DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5,
};

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUsers>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
})
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ManagementStudioDbContext>();
```

DocumentStudio relies on ManagementStudio to login as ManagementStudio contains all the user data and IdentityUser Model.

This is the login on DocumentStudio which is similar to the ManagementStudio one:

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUsers> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUsers> _userManager;
private readonly ApplicationUsersData applicationUsersData;

public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUsers> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUsers> userManager, ApplicationUsersData applicationUsersData)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    this.applicationUsersData = applicationUsersData;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null){
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
}
```

However, for some reason, this is the error I get when I try to login:

[image]

How can I handle this issue?

EDIT:

Added my ApplicationUsers

```
public class ApplicationUsers : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    private DateTime createdOn = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (createdOn == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : createdOn;
        }
        set
        {
            createdOn = value;
        }
    }
    private DateTime updatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (updatedOn == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : updatedOn;
        }
        set
        {
            updatedOn = value;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Added my DbContexts

Document Studio

```
public DocumentStudioDbContext(DbContextOptions<DocumentStudioDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
public DbSet<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
public DbSet<DocumentCategories> DocumentCategories { get; set; }
```

ManagementStudio

```
public ManagementStudioDbContext(DbContextOptions<ManagementStudioDbContext> options) : base(options){}
public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

EDIT 3:

I suspect its because DocumentStudio is looking for a its own ApplicationUser. ApplicationUser only makes sense to ManagementStudio. Maybe the solution is to override the passwordsigninasync and have one that calls ManagementStudios data.

Comment: Can you show please ApplicationUsers definition?

Comment: Does your ApplicationUser class extend/implement the IdentityUser class?

Comment: Hi Sam and Jamie, I have added my ApplicationUser to the question

Comment: Could you show the database context, my be your dbcontext was not implemented IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUsers>

Comment: And your DbContext looks like public class ManagementStudioDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUsers> ?

Comment: I've added both DbContexts

Comment: Its strange that its asking for ApplicationUsers only and not ManagementStudio.ApplicationUsers